# How many months of log data do you retain in Elasticsearch node consider best practices?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let say we have three nodes cluster and we have multiple server generating logs, and since we do not have retention policy implemented on elastic cluster " how do we need to implement it and how much data should we keep on cluster and for how long would be best practice ?

I have three cluster however not enough data yet but looking to get best answer from others.

No code required .

I would really want to get more people thoughts.

Comment: it depends on so many parameters it’s hard to even say anything

Comment: let discuss about parameters you have mentioned @DejanMarić

Comment: how big is the data, how much data per second/day, how many CPU, RAM etc.. your question is too wide